# Recursive relationship

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please help me to solve this question:

Recursive sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ on $\mathbb{Z}_2$  is defined with law

$$ \{a_n\} = \{a_{n-1}\} + \{a_{n-l}\} , \quad \forall \  n \geq l.$$

for any $n \geq 0$ place $ b_n = a_n +1$.

Define a recursive relationship on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ for sequence $b_n$.

Comment: 1. Compute $b_0$, $b_1$, $b_2$, etc. until you can make a conjecture.
2. Prove your conjecture, for example by induction.